# C++ choose base class to inherit from

Tags: c++, object, oop, templates, inheritance

I have a Class "Parent1" and another "Parent2", which symbolize different hardware implementations of a device "Subclass". What is the most elegant way of implementing this? I have thought about using templates e.g.

```
class Parent1{
public:
   Parent1():
   void run();
};

class Parent2{
public:
   Parent2():
   void run();
};

template<typename Parent>
class Subclass : Parent {
public:
    Subclass();
    void doSomething(){Parent:run();}
}:
```

But then the Subclass does not know the run() function from the base class.

I also thought about making the Subclass an interface class with the methods that the Subclass needs to inherit from the Parents being pure virtual functions that are then specified in a further subclass that inherits from the chosen class.

I believe this could be ok for this particular application since there is not a huge number of methods I would need to virtualize but I am wondering if that would scale. So my solution would look like this.

```
class Subclass {
public:
    Subclass();
    virtual void run()=0;
    void doSomething(){run();}
}:

class SubSubclass1 : Subclass, Parent1{
public:
    SubSubclass1():Subclass(),Parent1(){}
    void run(){Parent1:run();}
};

class SubSubclass2 : Subclass, Parent2{
public:
    SubSubclass2():Subclass(),Parent2(){}
    void run(){Parent2:run();}
};
```

but I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: `But then the Subclass does not know the run() function from the base class.` It does.

Comment: *"But then the Subclass does not know the run() function from the base class."* - can you elaborate on this statement? Why would it not be able to call a base class function?

Comment: Your original code compiles once you fix various problem with `:`, in C++ `Subclass` does not need to know where `run()` comes from.

Comment: `Parent1():` should be `Parent1();`. `Parent2:run();` should be `Parent2::run();` Also `Subclass` should have `;` instead of `:` in the class declaration.

Comment: You're doing it backwards.   Look up polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just implement a base interface class for the two "Parents"?

```cpp
class IBase
{
    virtual ~IBase();
    virtual void run(); 
};

class Parent1 : public IBase
{
public:
   Parent1();
   void run(); // implement
};

class Parent2 : public IBase
{
public:
   Parent2();
   void run(); // implement
};
```

Then you can use an IBase pointer to point at the actual "Parent" object.

**Update:**
Example to use this

```cpp
int main()
{
    Parent1 p1;
    Parent2 p2;
    IBase* basePtr;
    
    basePtr = &p1;
    basePtr->run(); // runs Parent1::run() for p1

    basePtr = &p2;
    basePtr->run(); // runs Parent2::run() for p2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on what you mean by the IBase pointer pointing at the actual parent object? What way would I tell the Subclass which Parent to use?